# Locating execution logs for SandboxPostCopy script?

Tags: apex, sandbox, sandbox-refresh

I have a Apex SandboxPostCopy script that should have been executed when I refreshed a sandbox recently, but it appears to either be not executing or failing to execute properly.

Is there anywhere I can see refresh logs in general? If not (and I'm assuming there is not) is there anywhere I can see logs for just this script, if it was executed?

Comment: I think you need to approach this from two directions. First, write a unit test for your script and make sure it passes, complete with assertions. Once you're that far, at least, I think you could probably set up a Debug Log in production for 24 hours on your user account, then do your refresh. I can't test this, but I theorize that if any logs are going to be generated, this should do it. Try it on a Dev Sandbox first, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

I do have unit tests setup (that really do assertions) so I know that the components of the script are actually doing what they are supposed to do. I will try setting up the debug log and kicking off a refresh, but if the refresh itself takes more than 24 hours then I'm SOL I think.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a class after creating a sandbox and added some debug statements. The logs appear on the newly created Sandbox's debug logs. Be sure to uncheck Show my current logs only on the Debug Tab